# Swift debugger appearing to visit wrong part of if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement

I am having problems tracing the following code:

```
print("%i", session.subsessions.count)    // prints 3
print("%i", self.iSessionNumber)          // prints 6
print("%i", self.sessions.count - 1)      // prints 6
if session.subsessions.count > 1 || self.iSessionNumber == self.sessions.count - 1
{
    // if called
}
else
{

}
```

Clearly, if condition should be called. But strangely, else is getting called. No idea why.

### Update

The reason it seemed else block was being called was because it was empty. This leads to my observation: the control from if line went directly to the end of if condition without executing the code within if block. Then the debugger again came to if line and if block got called. I still don't understand the behaviour of debugger, which was again executing the if-else statement.

Comment: As a sanity check, do you see the same printout if you put the print statements inside the `else` section?

Comment: Maybe you are overriding a getter somewhere such that `isSessionNumber` or `self.session` is changing the count or a race condition.. too many to tell so we need more info..

Comment: Did you redefine the print function? `print("%i", session.subsessions.count)` would normally print `"%i 3"`, as it does not know about printf formats.

Comment: @MartinR : Yes the print says %i 3, %I 6, %I 6

Comment: @Nitish what's printed first code in  if or else ????

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Fellas, I found out something. Firstly else case was empty. And the control from if line went directly to the end of if condition without executing the code within if block. Then the debugger again came to if line and if block got called. I should have placed some code in else block for a start which is my mistake. But I am not able to understand the behaviour of debugger again executing the if-else statement.

Comment: I have seen quirks like this many times if a scope of code is actually empty. Just add something like `print("Hey Ho")`.

Comment: So this is not a problem that the wrong if-block is executed, but about what the *debugger* displays. You should update your question accordingly and make that clear.

Comment: @MartinR : Sure, right away.

Comment: @MartinR : I have updated my question. Please feel free to edit it if you find any way you can improve that.

Comment: I want to see the reasons for downvotes. @Moderators Kindly share as to what guidelines has this question crossed.

Answer (score 0):

Use brackets to make your code easier to read and more executable.

```
if ((session.subsessions.count > 1) || (self.iSessionNumber ==
 (self.sessions.count - 1)))
{
// if called
}
else
{
// else called
}
```

Also, if you haven't already tried debugging this way, try splitting up your conditions to see where it is failing...

```
if (session.subsessions.count > 1) 
{
    print('passed condition 1')
}
else if self.iSessionNumber == (self.sessions.count - 1)
{
    print('failed condition 1, passed condition 2')
}else
{
    print('no conditions passed')
    print("%i", session.subsessions.count)    // check the numbers
    print("%i", self.iSessionNumber)          
    print("%i", self.sessions.count - 1)    
}
```

This should tell you where it is failing and how to fix it.  Check your code to make sure you aren't changing these values dynamically and that they are still the same within your statements.

Comment: *"easier to read"* –  I disagree. And what does *"more executable"* mean?

Comment: More executable as in the second condition isn't clear enough and you can end up with problems writing it this way - if conditions get too complicated than you can't be sure they are running correctly.  At least for debugging purposes.  I find when debugging it's far easier to clearly read what you are testing if you have the right brackets... personal opinion though.  I understand not everyone feels that way.

Comment: I prefer the extra parenthesis because it makes it clear what the developer intended rather than trying to keep track of precedence rules while reading longer lines of code.

Comment: If you want easier to read code I would divide the iff condition into 2 and place them in method or computed properties `if hasPositiveSubsessionCount || isLastSession {…`

Comment: @vikingosegundo I was trying to give easier to read/debug with minimal changes but I agree with you 100% that it would be better to split them into computed properties